# CSS breadcrumb - how to make radius small

Tags: html, css

I have created a breadcrumb, but I'm struggling to set the border-radius correctly.

I'm using the css from the codepen mentioned in the comments.

[image]

1. *What I have*
2. *What I want*

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: http://codepen.io/arkev/pen/DzCKF

Comment: no code no chocolate ! ... how ever looks like you kept either a shadow or an unwanted border on the pseudo

Comment: lol ..I don't know .. may be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `rotateY(45deg)` transform to your `.breadcrumb a:after` pseudo-element: `transform: rotateY(45deg) scale(0.707) rotate(45deg);`. Beware: this will also thin the border a bit.